Huggingfacae TGI ERROR text_generation_launcher: Shard 0 failed to start
2024-05-02T17:06:59.807336Z  INFO download: text_generation_launcher: Successfully downloaded weights.
2024-05-02T17:06:59.807762Z  INFO shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Starting shard rank=0
2024-05-02T17:07:02.879107Z  WARN text_generation_launcher: Could not import Flash Attention enabled models: CUDA is not available
2024-05-02T17:07:03.812736Z ERROR shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Shard complete standard error output:
The installed version of bitsandbytes was compiled without GPU support. 8-bit optimizers, 8-bit multiplication, and GPU quantization are unavailable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/bin/text-generation-server", line 8, in 
sys.exit(app())
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/cli.py", line 71, in serve
from text_generation_server import server
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/server.py", line 17, in 
from text_generation_server.models.vlm_causal_lm import VlmCausalLMBatch
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/models/vlm_causal_lm.py", line 14, in 
from text_generation_server.models.flash_mistral import (
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/models/flash_mistral.py", line 18, in 
from text_generation_server.models.custom_modeling.flash_mistral_modeling import (
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/models/custom_modeling/flash_mistral_modeling.py", line 29, in 
from text_generation_server.utils import paged_attention, flash_attn
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/text_generation_server/utils/flash_attn.py", line 24, in 
raise ImportError("CUDA is not available")
ImportError: CUDA is not available
rank=0
2024-05-02T17:07:03.910103Z ERROR text_generation_launcher: Shard 0 failed to start
2024-05-02T17:07:03.910129Z  INFO text_generation_launcher: Shutting down shards
Error: ShardCannotStart
NVIDIA-SMI 470.239.06   Driver Version: 470.239.06   CUDA Version: 11.4
cuda is Installed nvidia-smi , nvcc --version matches bitsnbytes verion is also comaptible
pip install bitsandbytes-cuda114
Any suggestions appreciated?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
